How to extract birth and death year from string in R?
I have the first paragraph of Wikipedia articles from the wikifacts package (only for people). I like to extract birth year and year of death.
library(wikifacts)
library(tidyverse)

politicians <- data.frame(
  Name = c("Barack Obama", "Angela Merkel", "Nelson Mandela", "Margaret Thatcher", "Mahatma Gandhi"),
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE
)

politicians <- politicians %>% 
  mutate(First_Paragraph = substr(wiki_define(Name), 1, 200)) 

head(politicians)


> head(politicians)
               Name
1      Barack Obama
2     Angela Merkel
3    Nelson Mandela
4 Margaret Thatcher
5    Mahatma Gandhi
                                                                                                                                                                                           First_Paragraph
1 Barack Hussein Obama II (born August 4, 1961) is an American politician who served as the 44th president of the United States from 2009 to 2017. As a member of the Democratic Party, he was the first A
2  Angela Dorothea Merkel (German: [aŋˈɡɪːla doʁoˈteːa ˈmɛʁkl̩] ; née Kasner; born 17 July 1954) is a retired German politician who served as Chancellor of Germany from 2005 to 2021 and was the first wom
3  Nelson Rolihlahla Mandela ( man-DEH-lə; Xhosa: [xolíɬaɬa mandɛ̂ːla]; born Rolihlahla Mandela; 18 July 1918 – 5 December 2013) was a South African anti-apartheid activist, politician, and statesman who
4 Margaret Hilda Thatcher, Baroness Thatcher,  (née Roberts; 13 October 1925 – 8 April 2013) was a British stateswoman and Conservative politician who was Prime Minister of the United Kingdom from 1979 
5 Mohandas Karamchand Gandhi (ISO: Mōhanadāsa Karamacaṁda Gāṁdhī; 2 October 1869 – 30 January 1948) was an Indian lawyer, anti-colonial nationalist and political ethicist who employed nonviolent resista

I like to extract birth year, and if available year of death. Usually, these are the first two 4 digits that appear, or the first two 4 digits that are within the first pair of parentheses. I tried several ways of regular expressions of string extractions. What would be a nice and easy way, preferably in tidyverse logic to get birth and death year?

Maybe try https://query.wikidata.org/ to build the query and use wiki_query ?

An easy way to do this rather than using wikifacts is to just use rvest to get each Wikipedia page and look up the <span> with the class bday. This contains a YYYY-MM-DD formatted date, so it's easy to convert to a date object:
library(tidyverse)
library(rvest)

politicians %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(doc = list("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/" %>% 
      paste0(Name %>% stringr::str_replace_all(' ', '_')) %>%
      read_html())) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  mutate(DOB = map(doc, ~ .x %>%
                html_element('.bday') %>%
                html_text()) %>% unlist() %>% as.Date(),
         DOD = map(doc, function(x) {
               vals <- x %>%
                html_elements(xpath = paste0("//td[@class='infobox-data']/",
                                             "span[@style='display:none']")) %>%
                html_text()
               if(length(vals) == 2) substr(vals[2], 2, 11) else NA_character_
              }) %>% unlist() %>% as.Date()) %>%
  select(-doc)

#> # A tibble: 5 x 3
#>   Name              DOB        DOD       
#>   <chr>             <date>     <date>    
#> 1 Barack Obama      1961-08-04 NA        
#> 2 Angela Merkel     1954-07-17 NA        
#> 3 Nelson Mandela    1918-07-18 2013-12-05
#> 4 Margaret Thatcher 1925-10-13 2013-04-08
#> 5 Mahatma Gandhi    1869-10-02 1948-01-30


Nice approach, working perfect on the minimal data. Throwing errors on my sample. Trying to figure out the problem.

@Marco there may be some cases where the wikipedia page is not a simple replacing of spaces with underscores in the person's name, or there are disambiguation pages, or the page is not set up with that specific layout. It may be best to test specific subsets of your data frame to find out which names fail so you can narrow it down.

Do you also have a suggestion for the death year? There only seems to be a class deathplace.

Consider using URLencode to ensure you have a valid  url. Also this works just for birthdates but one could use regex to traverse the page for deaths

@Onyambu URLencode would be a sensible addition, but it won't ensure the url exists. This solution purposefully avoids regex in preference to reading off pre-labelled data fields, which is usually safer. I have added this method for deaths too

create the url using url <- paste0("https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?search=", URLencode(name)) . It would ensure the url exists. And would give results regardless of how the name is specified eg would work if the name passed is only obama or mandela etc

Here is a rather crude way of extracting the dates of birth and, if it exists, death.
Create a regex for each of the possible date formats paste them together with "|" as a separator and extract those strings. Then bind everything in a data.frame.
library(wikifacts)
#> Warning: package 'wikifacts' was built under R version 4.4.1
library(tidyverse)

politicians <- data.frame(
  Name = c("Barack Obama", "Angela Merkel", "Nelson Mandela", "Margaret Thatcher", "Mahatma Gandhi"),
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE
)

politicians <- politicians %>% 
  mutate(First_Paragraph = substr(wiki_define(Name), 1, 200)) 

# regex for dates "day month.name year"
pat1 <- sprintf("\\d+ %s \\d+", month.name) |> paste(collapse = "|")
# regex for dates "month.name day, year"
pat2 <- sprintf("%s \\d+, \\d+", month.name) |> paste(collapse = "|")
# combine the two patterns above
pat <- paste(pat1, pat2, collapse = "|")
dat <- str_extract_all(politicians$First_Paragraph, pat)
# do we have two dates?
Max <- dat |> lengths() |> max()
lapply(dat, \(x) if(length(x) == Max) x else c(x, NA_character_)) |>
  do.call(rbind.data.frame, args = _) |> 
  setNames(c("Birth", "Death"))
#>             Birth           Death
#> 1  August 4, 1961            <NA>
#> 2    17 July 1954            <NA>
#> 3    18 July 1918            <NA>
#> 4 13 October 1925    8 April 2013
#> 5  2 October 1869 30 January 1948

Created on 2024-06-25 with reprex v2.1.0

Good start. But when applying it to all my data, I notice that there are more patterns that are sometimes not captured like (; January 28, 1912 – August 11, 1956)  or 25 February 1841 – 3 December 1919)

Here is a function that could be used to get the information you want:
library(xml2)
    
dates <- function(name){
  url <- paste0("https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?search=", URLencode(name))
  html <- read_html(url)
  bdate <- xml_text(xml_find_first(html, "//span[@class='bday']"))
  name2 <- sub(" - Wikipedia", "", xml_text(xml_find_first(html, "//head/title")))
  response <- read_xml(paste0("https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=extracts&exsentences=",1,
                        "&exlimit=1&titles=", URLencode(name2), 
                        "&explaintext=1&format=xml"))
  string <- xml_text(xml_find_first(response, "query/pages/page/extract"))
  pat <- sprintf("(?<=%s)[^)]+",substr(bdate, 1, 4))
  ddate <- sub("\\W+", "", regmatches(string, regexpr(pat, string, perl = TRUE)))
  c(Birth = format(as.Date(bdate), "%d %B %Y"), 
    Death = if(length(ddate)) ddate else NA)
}
dates('mandela')
       Birth      Death
1 1918-07-18 2013-12-05

dates('obama')
       Birth Death
1 1961-08-04  <NA>

Now loop over the politicians:
data.frame(t(sapply(politicians$Name, dates)))
                            Birth           Death
Barack Obama       04 August 1961            <NA>
Angela Merkel        17 July 1954            <NA>
Nelson Mandela       18 July 1918 5 December 2013
Margaret Thatcher 13 October 1925    8 April 2013
Mahatma Gandhi    02 October 1869 30 January 1948

